# Sapply or for loop to apply grepl function over dataset?

Tags: r, function

I'm looking for the most elegant way to replace values in 32 columns of a dataset, currently all stored as factors. Looks like this:

```
   GENT CIP LEVO CB CT CTX
138                        
145        R          S    
156    S   S    S          
161    S   S    S          
173
```

As you can see, there are R's, S's, and lots of space...R's need to be 'Resistant', 'S's need to be 'Sensitive', and space needs to remain as-is.

The following works beautifully for a single variable (and thanks to those who answered my last question for providing this!!):

```
x <- as.character(drugs$CIP)
new <- rep(NA, length(x))
new[grepl("R", x)] <- "RESISTANT"
new[grepl("S", x)] <- "SENSITIVE"
```

Question is, how do I apply this over all the columns of the dataset at once? Thinking there may be an `sapply` solution, or a loop to be written, and I'm sure the answer is simple but I'm not used to writing functions so have found myself stuck....thanks again for all your help!!

Tried a nested 'ifelse' statement:

```
drugs[2:33]<-ifelse(drugs[3:33] == 'R', 'RESISTANT', ifelse(drugs[3:33] == 
'S', 'SENSITIVE', ifelse(drugs[3:33] == "", "", "")))
```

And received the following.

> Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, 2:33, value = c("", "", "", "", "",  : 
>     replacement has 2325 items, need 2400

Update: posted the sample data as requested, and was messing about with some of the answers...nothing quite working yet, but I think my fault for an unclear question. Help is much appreciated!! Thanks, stackoverflow.

Comment: Updated the post. Please check if that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is similar to one I created and assuming that there are only three levels (`R`, `S`, and `''`) for each of the columns (3:33).

```
 drugs[3:33] <-  ifelse(drugs[3:33] =='R', 'RESISTANT', 
                    ifelse(drugs[3:33]=='S', 'SENSITIVE', ''))
```

Or

```
 drugs[,3:33] <- `dim<-`(factor(as.matrix(drugs[3:33]), 
     levels=c('', 'S', 'R'), labels=c('', 'SENSITIVE', 'RESISTANT')),
                   dim(drugs2[3:33]))
```

Another option for big datasets will be using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(drugs)[, 3:33 := lapply(.SD, function(x) factor(x, 
    levels=c('', 'S', 'R'), labels=c('', 'SENSITIVE', 'RESISTANT'))),
       .SDcols=3:33][]
```

Or a potentially faster option would be to use `for` loop with `set`

```
setDT(drugs)
for(j in 3:33){
  set(drugs, i=NULL, j=j, value= factor(drugs[[j]], levels=c('', 'S', 'R'),
          labels=c('', 'SENSITIVE', 'RESISTANT')))
 }
```

#### data

```
set.seed(35)
m1 <- matrix(sample(c('R', 'S', ''), 10*31, replace=TRUE), ncol=31)
drugs <- data.frame(id=1:10, Someval=rnorm(10), m1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr` you could achieve this one of two ways:

1) tidyr::gather() the columns you want to recode the names of into two columns, `key` and `value`, recode the `value` variable as above, then use tidyr::spread() to spread the values back into separate columns.

2) Use the function dplyr::mutate_each().

If you want example code using either or both of these approaches let me know. Hopefully just knowing that there are these two simple ways of doing it is helpful, and using this it'll take just a few minutes to achieve the output you need.